# Turn a sequence of unrelated git commits into a branch

Tags: git

I would like to turn a sequence of arbitrary unrelated commits A, B, C, ... into a branch A'->B'->C'->... where each commit X' matches the state of the tree for the corresponding commit X. Commits can be unrelated, with different files, submodules etc. I consider to use repeated git diff-apply-commit, like in:

```
git checkout A
git checkout -b commits-as-branch
git diff HEAD B | git apply; git commit -a -m 'Like B'
git diff HEAD C | git apply; git commit -a -m 'Like C'
...
```

But the repository is huge (Chromium tree), the sequence contain thousands of commits and the diff between commits can be hundreds of megabytes. So I am looking for something more scalable.

Comment: git-cherry-pick is simpler than diff/apply/commit, and works fine on even orphaned commits, though I don't know about the scalability.

Comment: @matthew.tuck git-cherry-pick does not work here at all as commits are *unrelated*.  They are  results of  repeated merge-with-upstream, rebasing and squashing on different branches.  So there is no chain of commits that can go from A to B to cherry-pick or rebase.

Comment: Perhaps I'm missing something (and I'd like to know more if so), but I don't see why one needs to have the other as a parent. The whole point of cherry-pick is it takes a commit with one parent and ports it over to another potentially-very-different parent, essentially copying the patch but not the code from previous commits. The only use-case I've ever found for diff/apply is porting between different repos. When you say there is no chain from A to B, I'm assuming there is still a commit that is ultimately the parent of both. Also, there can be conflicts, but how could you avoid that?

Answer (score 4):

> I would like to turn a sequence of arbitrary unrelated commits A, B, C, ... into a branch A'->B'->C'->... where each commit X' matches the state of the tree for the corresponding commit X.

This is hard to do with user-oriented, normal everyday Git commands, and *trivially easy* to do with Git *plumbing* commands.  Specifically you want to use `git commit-tree` to make the commits, with the trees involved being those from commits `A`, `B`, `C`, and so on, and the commit messages perhaps taken from those commits as well, but you want the parent of commit `A'` to be some chosen commit—in your setup that would be `HEAD`—and the parent of `B'` to be `A'`, the parent of `C'` to be `B'`, and so on.

(Note that this means you've drawn your commits the wrong way around.  That is, Git internally works *backwards*.  If you draw your commits the right way, that's the wrong way. )

Once you are done making this chain of commits that ends at the hash ID produced by the last of your `git commit-tree` commands, you can create your branch name, pointing to this last commit.  If you have the hash IDs of the commits you like in an input file, you would use, e.g.:

```
prev=HEAD    # could use prev=$(git rev-parse HEAD) but no need
newest=$prev
while read hash; do
    git log --no-walk --format=%B $hash > /tmp/commit-msg
    newest=$(git commit-tree -F /tmp/commitmsg -p $prev $hash^{tree})
    prev=$newest
done < commitlist

git checkout -b newbranch $newest
```

(written for clarity, rather than optimal performance: use pipes instead of temporary files, simplify away unneeded variables, and so on to improve it, and add error checking if/as needed).

Note: untested.

Comment: Some pull requests =). 1) `git log --format=%B -1 $hash`. 2) `git checkout -b newbranch $newest`. 3) `done < commits.txt`.

Comment: @ElpieKay: oops, right. I prefer `--no-walk` to `-1` for purely theoretical reasons (well, for this case at least), so I kept the `--no-walk`, though.

Comment: I didn't know `--no-walk` existed. Learned something new from you as always.

Comment: Big thanks! I suspected that it will be straightforward, but just few lines of sh script??? Git is powerful!

Comment: It turned out that I needed to preserve the author and date of the original commit. So I modified the script to extract that using %an, %ae, %ad arguments to git log --format= and pass that to git commit-tree as GIT_AUTHOR_NAME, GIT_AUTHOR_EMAIL and GIT_AUTHOR_DATE variables.

Comment: @IgorBukanov: yes, that's the way to do it. Note, `git format-patch` (the old shell script version) has some shell code to do this cleverly.